# How to add the Edittext up when i open the relative layout with fragment class which is from other class

Tags: android, emoji

In edittext when we write the text at that time the keyboard is open
and when we write the data which is more then the size of the it at
that time the text is scroll and goes up side.

my question is when we write in edittext autometically keybord open and the edittext goes up right??? now how should i do for the same thing when i open the emojes and edittext should go upside??

Now i am using the emojie's in my app.
    Like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/emojicons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            class="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i open the emojies fragment class at that time the edittext is not goes up side. So My question is how to do that?

For more understand my question here i put the linkes for showing the images.[image]

[image]

Comment: Any body help me plz.......

Comment: my question is when we write in edittext autometically keybord open and the edittext goes up right??? now how should i do for the same thing when i open the emojes??